# Creating a pipeline using map and filter, instead of for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

Write a function `fact(lst,f)` that given a list of lists, for example: `((30, 80, 72, 40), (24,), (88, 50, 34, 90, 56))` where each list contains student grades, multiply each student grade by `f`, and return a new list of lists where each list contains `[min, max, average]` grades.

given the list above, the function will return this list: `((45.0, 100, 76.25), (36.0, 36.0, 36.0), (51.0, 100, 82.0))`

can not use for loops, only built-in functions.

so far I have managed to multiply each item in each list by `f`:

```py
def fact(lst,f):
 new_lst = tuple(map(lambda x: tuple(map(lambda y: y*f, x)), lst))
 return new_lst
```

```py
lst = ((30, 80, 72, 40), (24,), (88, 50, 34, 90, 56))
print(fact(lst,1.5))
```

this prints `((45.0, 120.0, 108.0, 60.0), (36.0,), (132.0, 75.0, 51.0, 135.0, 84.0))`

My problem is that student grades can not exceed 100, and I can't figure out which function to use, in order to "limit" the grades.

after that I believe using `min()`, `max()`, and `reduce()` (for the average grade) would be the right way.

Comment: min(grade, 100) will cap it at 100, without any other changes

Comment: @KennyOstrom Thank you, this solved my problem.